# echo a picture from a path on server with name of the picture in a sql

Tags: php

I am looking for a solution for my issue, the code that i am now using will show the file name and not the picture itself. I think there is something wrong on my echo code.

This is my code that I am using :

```
echo "<table class=showtable>";
echo "<tr>
<td class=show >".$row['ID']."</td>
<td class=show2>".$row['DateTime']."</td>
<td class=show3>".$row['Stock']."</td>
<td class=show4>".$typeArray[$row['Type']]."</td>
<td class=show5>".$tradeArray[$row['Trade']]."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Entry']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Stoploss']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target1']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target2']."</td>
<td class=show6>".$row['Explination']."</td>
<td class=show7>'<img src='/trades.tiniduske.be/upload/'/>". print $row['Screenshot']  ." </td> </tr>";
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you add a little more code? Where do you initialise $row? How do you echo out the above line?

Comment: echo "<table class=showtable>";
echo "<tr>
<td class=show >".$row['ID']."</td>
<td class=show2>".$row['DateTime']."</td>
<td class=show3>".$row['Stock']."</td>
<td class=show4>".$typeArray[$row['Type']]."</td>
<td class=show5>".$tradeArray[$row['Trade']]."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Entry']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Stoploss']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target1']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target2']."</td>
<td class=show6>".$row['Explination']."</td>
<td class=show7>'<img src='/trades.tiniduske.be/upload/'/>". print $row['Screenshot'] ." </td> </tr>";
echo "</table>";

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td class=show7><img src="/home/tiniduske/domains/tiniduske.be/public_html/trades/upload/ . $row['Screenshot'] . '"/> </td> </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify webpath eg www.yourdomain.com/path_to_image where path_to_images is relative to your web root.. and not filesystem path on ur server.